# CMake write header file using GLOB result

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a GLOB expression such as:

```
file( GLOB HEADER_FILES path/*.h )
```

And would like to generate a header file that contains a definition for each HEADER_FILES entry. For example, if the file is called "path/my_class.h" then the macro should be:

```
#define PATH_MY_CLASS_FILE /full/path/to/path/my_class.h
```

This can be easily done using bash, but we also target windows and visual studio. Is there a pure CMAKE way to get this done? Or will I have to write a quick C++ program and make a custom dependency/target to generate the file?

---

Working from the answer I came up with this:

```
file(WRITE headers.h "//Generated headers include\n")
foreach(header_path ${APP_SHARED_MOC_HEADERS})
    # drop full name for macro name
    string(REPLACE "${INCLUDE_DIR}/" "" header "${header_path}")
    # drop extension
    string(REPLACE ".h" "" header "${header}")

    string(REPLACE "/" "_" header "${header}")
    string(TOUPPER "${header}" define_name)

    file(APPEND headers.h "#define PATH_${define_name} ${header_path}\n")
endforeach()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
file(GLOB HEADER_FILES path/*.h)

foreach(header ${HEADERS_FILES})
  # here replace / for linux and \ for windows
  string(REPLACE "/" "_" header_path header) 
  string(TOUPPER header_path final_header_path)
  file(APPEND headers_defines_file define 
    PATH_${final_header_path} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/header)
endforeach(header)
```

Comment: Thank you. With a few changes I have a solution.